# How do I target the child of a certain Node in firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a database that is structured with the following:

---

**Users**
     -User1
     --Buisiness_Name:
 
     --Buisiness_Role: 
     --Description: 
     --Name: 
     --Phone_Number

---

I have the following code:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users/" + user_id);
 firebase.database().ref().on('value', function(snapshot) {
   $'#bname').val((snapshot.val() && snapshot.val()));
   console.log(snapshot.val());
 });
```

How do I target only a certain child of the users/ directory with `snapshot`?

If my question is unclear, I will be glad to edit my question to improve it.

I need to also create a URL for every registered user.

Comment: Are you trying to get the entire document or just a single property from it?

Comment: A single property from it like name or buisiness_name

Comment: you can get at it just like a url `ref("cars/chevy/malibu/modelA")` or you can get at it with `.child("cars").child("chevy")`....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to get just a single property like `Business_Name`:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users/" + user_id + "/Business_Name");
//↓ You created the reference but didn't use it
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  //↓ you forgot the "(" here
  $('#bname').val((snapshot.val());
});
```

If you are trying to get the entire document:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users/" + user_id);
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  $('#bname').val((snapshot.val().Business_Name);
});
```

More info on getting, setting and updating data can be found in the [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the data of 'Phone_Number',
you can get the value by:

```
snapshot.val().Phone_Number
```

If you only want to get a single node data, like 'Phone_Number',
you can also point the ref directly into that node.

```
var Phone_NumberRef = firebase.database().ref("users/" + user_id + "/Phone_Number");
Phone_NumberRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Comment: Heh, you posted your answer while I was editing mine to include the same information.